Permissons error. Core.mjs.6484. What is causing this error?
I am getting an error message while trying to get data from a Firebase DB: Missing or insufficient permissions. Core.mjs.6484. I am getting a successful build of the application and I am trying to get an ID and some data associated with that ID. The codebase for this application is from an Angular University course that provided me with the skeleton application for the course.
I downloaded the course skeleton code and installed the application. It installed and compiled successfully. I connected the application to the firebase db by including the code to allow the connection. I then added the code to access the db and get an id and some data and that is when I get the missing or insufficient permissions error.
